# Displaying uploaded image only works every other time

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm working on a user account system for my website. I want users to be able to upload a custom profile picture. Currently, it displays a preview of the uploaded image. But it only works every other time. I can't seem to fix it.

Here is my code:

```php
<img id="pfp-img" src="<?php echo (empty($row["pfp"]) ? "https://www.media.yoo-babobo.com/images/user.png" : $row["pfp"]); ?>" alt="Your profile picture" onclick="$('#pfp').trigger('click');" style="width: 150px; height: auto; border-radius: 100%; cursor: pointer;" />
<input type="file" id="pfp" name="pfp" placeholder="Profile Picture" capture="user" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" />
```

And here is the javascript:

```js
$("#pfp").on("input change", e => {
    var canvas = $('<canvas width="150" height="150" style="display: none;">');
    $("body").append(canvas);

    var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150);
    }
    
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0] || "<DEFAULT PROFILE PICTURE>");

    var data_uri = document.querySelector("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");

    document.getElementById("pfp-img").src = data_uri;

    canvas.remove();
})
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? And are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: When you say every other time, is it consistent, i.e. Works, doesn't work, works, doesn't work, etc. Does it work on the first time you load the page every time?

Comment: No, it works the second time the page loads.